# Android layout with oblique bottom

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view

How can I achieve this kind of layout where the bottom line is sideways  :

I have simply no idea how it can be achieved.

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong but that's just an image with transparent triangle in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout`. In it - first you place `ImageView` of background image with birds, then in the same `RelativeLayout` you place white triangle image with align parent bottom, and thats it )

Comment: That could be a solution but I cannot use an image for that, it need to be flexible, for example to change the angle/color.. etc at runtime

Comment: believe me operate with static images in directory `drawable-nodpi` will take less memory then you will take when you start to do this programmatically ))